# Solution for the Gravitational acceleration for the equation with L'hospital Rule

Tags: physics, geodesy

> Let $b(r) = -G \iiint \frac {r-r_0}{||r-r_0||^3} dm$ be the gravitational acceleration, where $r_0$ is the center of mass of a rigid body. Show that $\lim_{r\to\infty} b(r) = 0$.

What is the geometrical interpretation for this?

I'm very new to this field of study and do not have much experience with this. It would be so helpful if somebody could explain the derivation for this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The interpretation is gravity is negligible at sufficient distance.

Comment: Your record is not very good. Let $r_0$ is radius vector of $dm$ and $r$ is radius vector of point where gravitational acceleration is calculated. Then given formula is correct. Let suppose that center of rigid body forming gravitational acceleration is $r_1$ and maximum distance from center for rigid body points is $R$. Then distance from $r$ such that $||r-r_1|| > R$ to rigid body points is from $||r-r_1||-R$ to $||r-r_1||+R$. Then $\frac1{||r-r_0||^2} \leq \frac1{(||r-r_1||-R)^2}$, then $||b(r)|| \leq \frac{Gm}{(||r-r_1||-R)^2}$. Then $\lim_{||r-r_1||\to\infty} b(r)=0$.